# Apply Tooltips on d3.js on multi-line chart issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, tooltip

Am trying to create a d3 **Multi-line chart** with given data.

I also want to implement a **tool tip on hover** showing the data of the line at **their intersections.**

My **Tool tip code:**

```
var tip = d3.tip()
        .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
        .offset([-10, 0])
        .html(function(d) {
            console.log(d);
            return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d + "</span>";
        });
```

My **issues:**

1) Currently its **showing undefined**,which is supposed to show the data.

2) It should be shown at **the intersections.**

How do i proceed to achieve that?

Here's [**My fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nevinm/DLjz6/3/)

Here's what i **want to achieve:**

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/Matthew-Weber/5645518)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Hey thanx for the example. I understood the logic of creating a circle having the points of the intersection as the center.
But i cant fix the undefined problem.

Comment: You are using a completely different approach. In particular, you're not binding data to the DOM elements -- this is the cause for the undefined thing. In addition, you also need to add the circles as separate elements; attaching a tooltip to the lines won't work.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I have updated the fiddle,with the circle on the intersection code. BUt i cant seem to bind the data properly.

Comment: You're not binding data to the lines at all. You need to use the usual D3 `.selectAll(..).data(..)` pattern for this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff My data is kinda an array of objects and that's what making it all complicated for me. 
Shouldn't this suffice -> .attr("d", line(dataArray[k]))
(Line 89 on fiddle)

Comment: Let me repeat that: *you are not binding any data*. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) for more information.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52269/discussion-between-nevin-madhukar-k-and-lars-kotthoff)